# .Net Mvc Swashbuckle own Index.page not rendering properly no javascript no css .Net Mvc Web Api

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

i making my own index page in swashbuckle in .net mvc web api. i copied source code from this link

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html

and when i run this web api i get this output

[Screen Shot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Moup.png)

i am using Swashbuckle.Core 1.0.0.0
Run-time version v4.0.30319

Please help me out
i more thing do i have put static CSS and JS file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are customizing the index.html page then you can add your own header by changing the addApiKeyAuthorization javascript function in the index.html page and by adding below properties in the SwaggerConfig.cs class.

SwaggerConfig.cs

```
config.EnableSwagger(
c =>
{
c.ApiKey("apiKey")
.Description("API Key Authentication")
.Name("apiKey")
.In("header");
})

function addApiKeyAuthorization() {
var key = encodeURIComponent($('#input_apiKey')[0].value);
if (key && key.trim() != "") {

key = "Bearer " + key;

          var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "header");
          window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", apiKeyAuth);
          log("added key " + key);
      }
  }
```

Comment: i saw this solution before but where to put function
Like i make one .js file but js file injecting is not working

Comment: Try to add scripts and CSS file in wwwroot folder and specifying the relative paths in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I found that renaming the folder containing my custom index.html from "Swagger" to something else fixed this problem.

See rbonstell's post in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/685).